# Property Injection into Web API's `System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute`

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Where is the recommended place to perform property injection into action filter attributes in an ASP.NET web api project? In MVC 3 land, we could set our own implementation for `ControllerActionInvoker` at the point of resolving our controllers from our IoC container, and override its `GetFilters()` method to inject components resolved from the container.

Is there a similar place to do this in an ASP.NET Web API project? I have a controller factory that resolves controllers from the container, with the `CreateController` method as so:

```
public IHttpController CreateController(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, string controllerName)
{
    var controller = _kernel.Resolve<IHttpController>(controllerName);

    controllerContext.Controller = controller;
    controllerContext.ControllerDescriptor = new HttpControllerDescriptor(_configuration, controllerName, controller.GetType());

    return controllerContext.Controller;
}
```

I've had a look at `HttpControllerDescriptor` to see if there is somewhere to do the injection, but I can't see a suitable place. Any pointers in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>You need to implement `IHttpControllerSelector` and register your selector in the (`Services` property) `DefaultServices` of the `HttpConfiguration`.</s>

Or alternatively, to use your own resolver/DI framework, you need to replace the resolver. See [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2012/04/01/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-web-api-using-autofac.aspx) for an example.

---

You need to Implement your own `IFilterProvider`. Have a look at the source for `ActionDescriptorFilterProvider`. This is where you can inject properties.

Here is `ActionDescriptorFilterProvider` implementation:

```
    public IEnumerable<FilterInfo> GetFilters(HttpConfiguration configuration, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        if (configuration == null)
        {
            throw Error.ArgumentNull("configuration");
        }

        if (actionDescriptor == null)
        {
            throw Error.ArgumentNull("actionDescriptor");
        }

        IEnumerable<FilterInfo> controllerFilters = actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetFilters().Select(instance => new FilterInfo(instance, FilterScope.Controller));
        IEnumerable<FilterInfo> actionFilters = actionDescriptor.GetFilters().Select(instance => new FilterInfo(instance, FilterScope.Action));

        return controllerFilters.Concat(actionFilters);
    }
```

All you have to do is to use `instance` lambda parameter and inject properties.

**Registration** As you have figured out, the filter provider needs to be registered against the `HttpConfiguration`. Or alternatively, to use your own resolver/DI framework, you need to replace the resolver. See [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2012/04/01/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-web-api-using-autofac.aspx) for an example.

Comment: `IHttpControllerSelector` doesn't help here - the problem isn't to do with resolving controllers correctly (this all works fine), but it's about injecting services into Action Filters. This is how one could do it in MVC - http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2008/11/08/dependency-injection-with-aspnet-mvc-action-filters/ , but Web API is slightly different.

Comment: @RussCam yes, misunderstood. Updated.

Comment: I came to the same result as you :) My `IFilterProvider` that is registered with the container however never seems to be hit; the Action Filters are running which suggests that the framework is not trying to resolve the `IFilterProvider` from the container. It's slightly frustrating as the source code on http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/ is out of date with the assemblies coming from NuGet!

Comment: Get the source and build it. At the end of the day, the final web api is gonna look more like the released source than the released beta installer. Well, at least I will do that. It is also APACHE 2.0 license which should be OK.

Comment: That last comment was a red herring :) I'd accidently registered the `System.Web.Mvc.IFilterProvider` and not the `System.Web.Http.Filters.IFilterProvider`. All seems fine now. If you could update your answer to say that the `IFilterProvider` should be registered with the container, I'll mark as accepted :)

Comment: @RussCam great. I will move some the crossed text down.

Comment: It's not real clear in this example how properties are "injected"

Comment: @drogon what is not clear? As I said you need to implement `IFilterProvider` which I have done for you. Then you need to register. Injection will be done by your DI framework - whatever it is - since this factory uses that.

Comment: What do you mean by "All you have to do is to use instance lambda parameter and inject properties."?