# BasicAuthHttpModule custom property resolve at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, ninject

I have a problem with ASP .NET Web API. I have followed the tutorial http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication and I have succesfully used it with sample code. However I would like to bind it with my AuthenticationService that I have made:

```
public class AuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
        private readonly GenericRepository<User> _userRepository;

        public AuthenticationService(GluEntities entites)
        {
            _userRepository = new GenericRepository<User>(entites);
        }

        public bool Authenticate(string userName, string password)
        {
            var user = _userRepository.Get(x => x.UserName == userName).FirstOrDefault();
            if (user == null || user.Password != password)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
}
```

i tried to tie it up with my sample code as follows:

```
public class BasicAuthHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
        private const string Realm = "GluService";
        private readonly IAuthenticationService _authenticationService;

        public BasicAuthHttpModule(IAuthenticationService authenticationService)
        {
            _authenticationService = authenticationService;
        }

        /... some irrelevant methods that are explained in the link

        private bool CheckPassword(string username, string password)
        {
            return _authenticationService.Authenticate(username, password);
        }

}
```

I am trying to resolve _authenticationService with ninject however the application throws Conustructor not found error at runtime. Any idea how can I resole _authenticationService at runtime so I can achieve maintainability and testability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Http modules are unlikely to be resolved by an ioc container, however, if you refactor your code to use an authentication filter rather than http module, you should be able to set up the mvc internal service locator to resolve your filter.

Take a look at this tutorial by Rick Strahl

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2013/Apr/18/A-WebAPI-Basic-Authentication-Authorization-Filter

and the IFilterProvider example

[Property Injection into Web API's `System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089823/property-injection-into-web-apis-system-web-http-filters-actionfilterattribute)

Comment: Thanks, it took me though few hours to figure out how to initialize and resolve custom IFilterProvider. Finally it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Wiktor I was able to glue together a code that actually works. Here is relevant code for future help. Other classes are in Wiktors' links.

```
public class NinjectFilterProvider : ActionDescriptorFilterProvider, IFilterProvider
    {
        private readonly IKernel _kernel;

        public NinjectFilterProvider(IKernel kernel)
        {
            _kernel = kernel;
        }

        public IEnumerable<FilterInfo> GetFilters(HttpConfiguration configuration, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
        {
            var filters = base.GetFilters(configuration, actionDescriptor);

            foreach (var filter in filters)
            {

                _kernel.Inject(filter.Instance);
            }

            return filters;
        }
    }

public static class NinjectWebCommon 
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the application
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Stop()
        {
            bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

            //Support WebApi
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectResolver(kernel);

            RegisterServices(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            //kernel.Bind<TCountingRepository>().To<CountingRepository>();
            //kernel.Bind<CountingContext>().To<CountinContext>();
            kernel.Bind<IAuthenticationService>().To<AlwaysAcceptAuthenticationService>();

            kernel.Bind<IFilterProvider>().To<NinjectFilterProvider>();
        }
    }
```

Here is filter

```
public class GluAuthenticationFilter : BasicAuthenticationFilter
    {
        [Inject]
        public IAuthenticationService AuthenticationService { get; set; }

        public GluAuthenticationFilter()
        { }

        public GluAuthenticationFilter(bool active)
            : base(active)
        { }


        protected override bool OnAuthorizeUser(string username, string password, HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            return AuthenticationService.Authenticate(username, password);
        }
    }
```